# In Excel, how can I reference a cell's appearance instead of its underneath value?

Tags: excel, reference

In Excel, how can I reference a cell's appearance (the displayed result) instead of its underneath value? For example:

1. Type `3.1415` in `A1` and press <kbd>Ctrl + Enter</kbd>
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + $</kbd>, `A1` will display the value as `$3.14`
3. Press <kbd>Alt + h 0</kbd> (hold <kbd>Alt</kbd>, press <kbd>h</kbd>, release both, press <kbd>0</kbd>), `A1` will display `$3.141`
4. In `A2`, type `="Amount: $3.141"`, `A2` will display `Amount: $3.141`.

My question is, in the cell `A2`, is there a way to reference `A1` and display `Amount: $3.141` instead of hardcoded `$3.141`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you have found the display is just a mask of the real number.  To do what you want you can apply the mask using TEXT and return a string in the same format:

```
="Amount: " & TEXT(A1,"$#,##0.000")
```

But the format is static.  The number will change as A1 changes, but the format or mask will not change if you change the format on A1.

BTW, All those keyboard short cuts can be done by simply applying a custom format of `$#,##0.000`

---

Now with a little vba we can actually use the text(display) value of the cell.  Put this code in a module attached to the workbook.

```
Function MyStr(rng As Range)
    MyStr = "Amount: " & rng.Text
End Function
```

And then you can call it from the sheet like a formula:

```
=MyStr(A1)
```

This will return what is displayed, so as the format is changed, you will need to force the recalculation of the sheet(F9), so will the output.